# how to insert/put a json array in the BasicDBObject

Tags: java, arrays, json, mongodb, bson

I am using [mongo db driver 2.11.2](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver/2.11.2). I am bit puzzled how to insert/add an array to the BasicDBObject. All the example which I come across are does not show how to achieve this :(. In the below example how would I insert employees array in the dbo object ?

```
 /*
    {
    "company" : "stackoverflow",
    "established": "when I started coding"
    "employees":[
        {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"},
        {"firstName":"Anna", "lastName":"Smith"},
        {"firstName":"Peter", "lastName":"Jones"}
       ]
    }
     */

    BasicDBObject basicDBObject = new BasicDBObject();
    basicDBObject.put("company", "stackoverflow");
    basicDBObject.put("established", "when I started coding");
    System.out.println(basicDBObject.toString());

}
```

Comment: Check Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852809/insert-array-inside-an-object-in-mongodb

Comment: AKS you are awesome , struggling for this for couple of hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Arrays.asList` as a contructor for the list. It's just a list. And `.append()` the object keys rather than "put". Again, it's just as [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) interface:

```
    BasicDBObject basicDBObject = new BasicDBObject();
    basicDBObject.put("company", "stackoverflow");
    basicDBObject.append("established", "when I started coding");
    basicDBObject.append("employees", Arrays.<DBObject>asList(
        new BasicDBObject("firstName", "john")
            .append("lastName", "doe"),
        new BasicDBObject("firstName", "anna")
            .append("lastName", "smith"),
        new BasicDBObject("firstName", "peter")
            .append("lastName", "jones")
    ));
    System.out.println(basicDBObject.toString());
```

Comment: just for the info, you have missed an comma after "smith"

Comment: @rockyit86 Cut and paste bites me every time. Did not have an IDE open and just typed in here.

Comment: no worries , I cannot type anything without an IDE , such a poor typist, and I guess I am not alone :)